# RollupError: Can't find stylesheet to import for using scss alias path

Tags: javascript, sass, rollupjs

I am trying make a react component library using typescript, scss & rollup for bundling. For my better development experience I am using path alias.

```
elementus/
┣ src/
┃ ┣ scss/
┃ ┃ ┣ mixins/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ _colors.scss
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ _flex.scss
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ _font.scss
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ _media.scss
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ _typography.scss
┃ ┃ ┗ _variables.scss
┃ ┣ ui/
┃ ┃ ┗ button/
┃ ┃   ┣ Button.stories.tsx
┃ ┃   ┣ Button.tsx
┃ ┃   ┣ button.module.scss
┃ ┃   ┗ index.ts
┃ ┣ utils/
┃ ┃ ┣ classNames.ts
┃ ┃ ┗ index.ts
┃ ┣ globals.d.ts
┃ ┗ index.ts
┣ .eslintrc.cjs
┣ .gitignore
┣ README.md
┣ package-lock.json
┣ package.json
┣ rollup.config.mjs
┣ tsconfig.json
┣ tsconfig.node.json
┗ vite.config.ts
```

this is my folder structure. I am using import @use "@scss/mixins/media" in button.module.scss. @scss is equivalent to "src/scss" that I config vite.config.ts and tsconfig.json

```
import alias from "@rollup/plugin-alias";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import postcssImport from "postcss-import";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import stringHash from "string-hash";
// const extensions = [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"];
// const excludes = [".stories.tsx"];
// const globals = {
//   react: "React",
//   "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
// };

export default {
  input: ["./src/index.ts"],
  output: {
    dir: "lib",
    format: "esm",
    sourcemap: true,
    preserveModules: true,
    preserveModulesRoot: "src",
  },
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    typescript(),
    alias({
      resolve: [".scss"],
      replacements: {
        "@scss": "./src/scss",
      },
    }),

    terser(),
    postcss({
      plugins: [postcssImport()],
      extensions: [".scss"],
      minimize: true,
      modules: {
        generateScopedName: (name, filename, css) => {
          if (filename.includes("global")) {
            return name;
          }
          const hash = stringHash(css).toString(36).substring(0, 5);
          return `elementus_${name}_${hash}`;
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

this is my rollup.config.js file code. When I build "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs" using this command it's showing error that it's can't find @use "@scss/mixins/media"; Cleary see in image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l7TJ.png)